# Do we need the Autobots?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-dark-of-the-moon

I recently watched *Transformers: Dark of the Moon*, in which humans attempt to get rid of the Autobots. After we send them off on the rocket the Decepticons attack, and the humans begin to fight back. It is my opinion that, although Autobots do have amazing offensive weapons it appears (in the movie) that the humans are able to hold their own against them; granted, our loses would be incredible since you have to assume it will take at least a reinforced squad to take down one of them.

I haven't seen the most recent *Transformers*, so I don't know if that might be the premise. However, in the world of *Transformers* have the humans fought the Decepticons on their own?  Do the movies accurately portray the ability to take them down with small arms?

Comment: If there were no Autobots then the film-makers couldn't sell as many toys and there would be no sequels.

Comment: Right, in the end it is a movie.  I never actually followed the cartoons, and I don't know how in depth the story actually goes. It just got me thinking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In the film universe: Yes!**

- While the humans were capable of taking down a few Decepticons on their own, keep in mind that had Sentinel's plan succeeded, and Cybertron had been teleported right next to Earth, no amount of human forces would've been sufficient to stop the Decepticons. The only reason it didn't succeed was because the Autobots intervened.
- Even in *Dark of The Moon*, the SEALs strike only after Sam and gang were able to take a closer look inside the city with the help of the Autobots.
- Had Optimus not killed Shockwave's Dragon, there's simply no way the ground forces would've been able to do a thing.

So, in summary, without the Autobots' help, the humans wouldn't stand a chance. The Decepticon forces were massive, and near undefeatable. Eventually they would've wiped out the human forces without a sweat.